# Stored Procedure for inserting/updating database from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, database-cursor

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 which takes data from XML file and inserts/updates it into database table.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcItem]
   (@cItemID nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @XMLdata XML)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    item_cursor cursor for 
    SELECT TempTable.i.value('ItemID[1]','nvarchar(50)')
    FROM @XMLdata.nodes('/Garage/WareHouse/ItemGroup/Item')AS TempTable(i)
open item_cursor;
fetch next from item_cursor into @cItemID
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT ItemID FROM WareHouse WHERE ItemID = @cItemID)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE WareHouse
    SET 
    ItemGroupID = TempTable.a.value('ItemGroupID[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Color = TempTable.a.value('Color[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Location = TempTable.a.value('Location[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Price = TempTable.a.value('Price[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Manufacture = TempTable.a.value('Manufacture[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
    Supplier = TempTable.a.value('Supplier[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
    SerialNumber = TempTable.a.value('SerialNumber[1]','nvarchar(100)')
    FROM
    @XMLdata.nodes('/Garage/WareHouse/ItemGroup/Item')AS TempTable(a)
    WHERE  ItemID = TempTable.a.value('ItemID[1]','nvarchar(100)')
    END

ELSE 
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO WareHouse (ItemID, ItemGoupID, Color, Location, Price, Manufacture, Supplier, SerialNumber)

    SELECT
    ItemID = TempTable.b.value('ItemID[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    ItemGroupID = TempTable.b.value('ItemGroupID[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Color = TempTable.b.value('Color[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Location = TempTable.b.value('Location[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Price = TempTable.b.value('Price[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
    Manufacture = TempTable.b.value('Manufacture[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
    Supplier = TempTable.b.value('Supplier[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
    SerialNumber = TempTable.b.value('SerialNumber[1]','nvarchar(100)')
    FROM
    @XMLdata.nodes('/Garage/WareHouse/ItemGroup/Item')AS TempTable(b)
    END
fetch next from item_cursor into @cItemID
END
close item_cursor
deallocate item_cursor
END
```

And my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Garage>
<WareHouse>
<WareHouseID>195</HallID>
<Name>CC Cuts</Name>
<Location>Boston</Location>
<ItemGroup>
<WareHouseID>195</WareHouseID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Name>C Parts</Name>
<Item>
<ItemID>645</ItemID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Color>Red</Color>
<Location>B Wing</Location>
<Price>165.00</Price>
<Manufacture>Danish igc</Manufacture>
<Supplier>TransEuro</Supplier>
<SerialNumber>1645570683</SerialNumber>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemID>646</ItemID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Color>Red</Color>
<Location>B Wing</Location>
<Price>165.00</Price>
<Manufacture>Danish igc</Manufacture>
<Supplier>TransEuro</Supplier>
<SerialNumber>1645570684</SerialNumber>
</Item>
...
</ItemGroup>
</WareHouse>
</Garage>
```

Code works, but if I'm trying to add a larger XML file it takes enormous time to complete. I believe it is because I'm using cursor. Is there another more efficient way to insert/update data from xml file? And maybe someone could give me an example.

Comment: The cursor is killing you dude.

Comment: Google "Sql Server RBAR".  "Row by Agonizing Row" is a performance killer.

Comment: You can do what you need to do, 99.9% of the time without a cursor.  "Set based" is the antithesis to "rbar" where a cursor is a tell-tale of rbar. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a @variable or #temp table.
2. "Shred" the xml into the @variable or #temp table.
3. Update/Insert from the @variable or #temp table.

Something like this:

```
declare @XMLdata xml
select @XMLdata = 
'
<Garage>
<WareHouse>
<WareHouseID>195</WareHouseID>
<Name>CC Cuts</Name>
<Location>Boston</Location>
<ItemGroup>
<WareHouseID>195</WareHouseID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Name>C Parts</Name>
<Item>
<ItemID>645</ItemID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Color>Red</Color>
<Location>B Wing</Location>
<Price>165.00</Price>
<Manufacture>Danish igc</Manufacture>
<Supplier>TransEuro</Supplier>
<SerialNumber>1645570683</SerialNumber>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemID>646</ItemID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Color>Red</Color>
<Location>B Wing</Location>
<Price>165.00</Price>
<Manufacture>Danish igc</Manufacture>
<Supplier>TransEuro</Supplier>
<SerialNumber>1645570684</SerialNumber>
</Item>
</ItemGroup>
</WareHouse>
</Garage>
'




    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HolderOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #HolderOne
    end


    CREATE TABLE #HolderOne
    ( 
    SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1)
    ,  ItemGroupID nvarchar(50)
    , Color nvarchar(50)
    , Location nvarchar(50)
    , Price nvarchar(50)
    , Manufacture nvarchar(100)
    , Supplier nvarchar(100)
    , SerialNumber nvarchar(100)
    )

    INSERT INTO #HolderOne ( 
          ItemGroupID
        , Color
        , Location
        , Price
        , Manufacture
        , Supplier
        , SerialNumber
    )

    Select 
     xmlAlias.a.value('ItemGroupID[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
        Color = xmlAlias.a.value('Color[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
        Location = xmlAlias.a.value('Location[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
        Price = xmlAlias.a.value('Price[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
        Manufacture = xmlAlias.a.value('Manufacture[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
        Supplier = xmlAlias.a.value('Supplier[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
        SerialNumber = xmlAlias.a.value('SerialNumber[1]','nvarchar(100)')
        FROM
        @XMLdata.nodes('/Garage/WareHouse/ItemGroup/Item')AS xmlAlias(a)


    Select * from #HolderOne

    INSERT INTO WareHouse (ItemID, ItemGroupID, Color, Location, Price, Manufacture, Supplier, SerialNumber)
    Select
        0
        ,  ItemGroupID
        , Color
        , Location
        , Price
        , Manufacture
        , Supplier
        , SerialNumber  
    from #HolderOne holder
        where not exists ( select null from dbo.WareHouse innerRealTable where innerRealTable.ItemGroupID = holder.ItemGroupID )

    Update WareHouse
    Set 
            ItemGroupID = holder.ItemGroupID
        , Color = holder.Color
        , Location = holder.Location
        , Price = holder.Price
        , Manufacture = holder.Manufacture
        , Supplier = holder.Supplier
        , SerialNumber = holder.SerialNumber
    from #HolderOne holder , dbo.WareHouse  ware
    Where
        holder.ItemGroupID = ware.ItemGroupID




    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HolderOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #HolderOne
    end
```

Here is the slightly improved @variableTable code...

```
declare @XMLdata xml
select @XMLdata = 
'
<Garage>
<WareHouse>
<WareHouseID>195</WareHouseID>
<Name>CC Cuts</Name>
<Location>Boston</Location>
<ItemGroup>
<WareHouseID>195</WareHouseID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Name>C Parts</Name>
<Item>
<ItemID>645</ItemID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Color>Red</Color>
<Location>B Wing</Location>
<Price>165.00</Price>
<Manufacture>Danish igc</Manufacture>
<Supplier>TransEuro</Supplier>
<SerialNumber>1645570683</SerialNumber>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemID>646</ItemID>
<ItemGroupID>235</ItemGroupID>
<Color>Red</Color>
<Location>B Wing</Location>
<Price>165.00</Price>
<Manufacture>Danish igc</Manufacture>
<Supplier>TransEuro</Supplier>
<SerialNumber>1645570684</SerialNumber>
</Item>
</ItemGroup>
</WareHouse>
</Garage>
'



    /* changed to use @variable table
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HolderOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #HolderOne
    end
    */


    /*CREATE TABLE #HolderOne*/
    Declare @HolderOne Table
    ( 
    SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1)
    , ItemID int
    , ItemGroupID int
    , Color nvarchar(50)
    , Location nvarchar(50)
    , Price nvarchar(50)
    , Manufacture nvarchar(100)
    , Supplier nvarchar(100)
    , SerialNumber nvarchar(100)
    )

    INSERT INTO @HolderOne ( 
          ItemID
        , ItemGroupID
        , Color
        , Location
        , Price
        , Manufacture
        , Supplier
        , SerialNumber
    )

    Select 
        xmlAlias.a.value('ItemID[1]','int'),
        xmlAlias.a.value('ItemGroupID[1]','int'),
        xmlAlias.a.value('Color[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
        xmlAlias.a.value('Location[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
        xmlAlias.a.value('Price[1]','nvarchar(50)'),
        xmlAlias.a.value('Manufacture[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
        xmlAlias.a.value('Supplier[1]','nvarchar(100)'),
        xmlAlias.a.value('SerialNumber[1]','nvarchar(100)')
        FROM
        @XMLdata.nodes('/Garage/WareHouse/ItemGroup/Item')AS xmlAlias(a)


    Select * from @HolderOne


    INSERT INTO WareHouse (/* ItemID, */ ItemGroupID, Color, Location, Price, Manufacture, Supplier, SerialNumber)
    Select
          /*holder.ItemId  , */
          holder.ItemGroupID
        , holder.Color
        , holder.Location
        , holder.Price
        , holder.Manufacture
        , holder.Supplier
        , holder.SerialNumber  
    from @HolderOne holder
        where not exists ( select null from dbo.WareHouse innerRealTable where innerRealTable.ItemId = holder.ItemId )

    Update WareHouse
    Set 
          ItemGroupID = holder.ItemGroupID
        , Color = holder.Color
        , Location = holder.Location
        , Price = holder.Price
        , Manufacture = holder.Manufacture
        , Supplier = holder.Supplier
        , SerialNumber = holder.SerialNumber
    from @HolderOne holder , dbo.WareHouse  ware
    Where
        holder.ItemId = ware.ItemId



        /* Changed to use variable table
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HolderOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #HolderOne
    end
    */
```

Comment: Where I have "innerRealTable.ItemGroupID = holder.ItemGroupID" and "holder.ItemGroupID = ware.ItemGroupID", you'll need to adjust for what your unique constraint is.  But it should be enough to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: This should exponentially improve performance.. the "set based" approach.  Don't look back (at rbar) dude....don't look back.

Comment: Note, if data like "ItemID" and "ItemGroupID" are always int, adjust your xml-shredding to go ahead and cast them as a int.  Example :    "CREATE TABLE #HolderOne     (   ItemGroupID int )"  and "xmlAlias.a.value('ItemGroupID[1]','int')"

Comment: I appended my answer to use @ variable Table.  Which one should you used? (variable vs #temp).  Most times, @ variable table is the general rule of thumb.  But very large xml's, testing with a #temp table version is worth the effort.  That also depends on a #temp table setup.  Which is a topic unto itself in a large scale enterprise database.  I would go with the @variable table most of the time.

Comment: Can you pleas tell me how can I use this approach to work with hierarchies, where children has their own children.?